# JUnit instantiating object every time a test case method runs

Tags: java, junit, junit4

**Test case:**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue; 
import org.junit.Test;
       
        
public class PendingTest {
    PendingUtil pendingUtil = new PendingUtil();
    boolean result;
    
    @Test
    public void fetchPendingWFFromDB(){
        result = pendingUtil.fetchPendingWFFromDB();
        assertTrue(result);
    }
            
    
     @Test
     public void runPendingBatch() {
     result = pendingUtil.runPendingBatch();
                assertTrue(result);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void checkQueuePostPendingRun() {
                result = pendingUtil.checkQueuePostPendingRun();
                assertTrue(result);
    }
}
```

**Class called from JUnit test case.**

```
public class PendingUtil {

    public PendingUtil() {
        try {
            System.out.println("In Const");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In my test case I only create the object once:

```
    PendingUtil pendingUtil = new PendingUtil();
```

But internally JUnit calls the constructor three times.

Why is this happening?

Comment: This is simply how JUnit works: it creates a new instance for every individual test method to execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create the `pendingUtil` in a `@BeforeClass` method.

Comment: It would have to be `static` then, so you might as well initialize it where it is done now.

Comment: +1 and the documentation may be found at http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html

Answer (score 21):

You've annotated 3 methods with `@Test`. From the [JUnit API doc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) on this annotation: `To run the method, JUnit first constructs a fresh instance of the class then invokes the annotated method.`

In short, the entire test class is instanced 3 times, and therefore, so is `PendingUtil` (once from each subsequent instance of the test class).

To do what you want, keep the property definition where it is, but assign the `PendingUtil` instance to it in a new method annotated with the [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) annotation.

Additionally, you could mark the property as static as suggested by vikingsteve.

Answer (score 1):

Hey just for update with Junit5,

> You could create the pendingUtil in a @BeforeAllmethod.

or like below:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class PendingTest {
}
```

Just for sake of knowledge, we can make that Lifecycle.PER_METHOD if we need to create fresh instance per method.

Answer (score 0):

Conversely if you do not want the PendingUtil to be called thrice you should probably write a TestUtil wrapper which probably just puts a Factory method in front of `new PendingUtil()` and only creates one instance.

Comment: That seems needlessly complicated. Alternative could be to make the property static and treat it as a singleton instance in a `@Before` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could make pendingUtil static

```
static PendingUtil pendingUtil = new PendingUtil();
```

Comment: No, you are right, of course. I removed the comment because it was obviously false. Thanks for notifying!